# What were Cantor’s “real numbers of higher type”?

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

In the preamble to “Essays on the Theory of Numbers”, Dedekind makes passing reference to a theory (expounded in Cantor’s “Ueber die Ausdenung eines Satzes aus der Theorie der trigonometrischen Reihen”) of “real numbers of higher type”. What are these, in modern terms?

Comment: See [here](https://www.aleph1.info/?call=Puc&permalink=reellezahlen_1_3_Z11) a ref to original [Cantor (1872)](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Cantor/Ausdehnung/Ausdehnung.pdf) : "Cantor suggests an iteration of the closure of a number domain that is possible up to the [transfinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_number). This iteration was still important to Cantor later, but it did not convince Dedekind and has had no effect to this day."

Comment: @Mauro Allegranza: Thank you. What kind of iterated closure was Cantor talking about?

Comment: Higher closure properties that would fill in transfinite rather than only countable "gaps" lead to what is now called [surreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number) introduced by Conway. But Cantor did not do much in this direction and they were not explored until a century later.

Comment: @Conifold: You say "Cantor did not do much in this direction", but can you tell me more about what he DID do? Also: I'm aware that the surreal numbers can be constructed via transfinite induction using a variant of Dedekind's cut-construction. However, Cantor's way of constructing the reals was via equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of rationals, and I don't see how a transfinite version of this construction would give the surreal numbers.

Comment: Essentially nothing, he floated a vague idea with Dedekind, who was skeptical, and left it at that. But one can get surreal numbers using transfinite Cauchy sequences, see [Kyritsis, The continuum of the surreal numbers revisited](https://hal.science/hal-03374400).